# VS 2013 unhandled win32 exception when debugging portable dll on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, async-await, windows-8.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 w/ Update 2 on Windows 8.1. I have some newly written code in a portable library targeting Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. When debugging a unit test on Windows 8.1, I get the following error popup: "A debugger is attached to vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception. To debug this exception, detach the current debugger."

[image]

Unfortunately, it does not appear possible to detach the current debugger; I'm trapped in the modal dialog.

My code is a bit too complicated to show here. I'm going to try to prune it down to the minimum. I also tried running the same code in a simple sample app, but I'm getting strange issues in this context as well (the debugger just seems to lose the context; I don't see any errors - but my code just seems to hang at semi-random locations).

I've also tried configuring the debugger to break when exceptions are thrown. But there are no exceptions.

This is very confusing for me. I strongly believe my code is somehow responsible, but crashing the IDE doesn't seem like a thing I should be able to do in code.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: code would certainly help, break pointing to narrow down what steps are failing in particular may help reduce the amount of code you would have to add to your question.  I see you tagged Asynch, if break pointing is difficult for your use case, using a logger inside of your async functions, or maybe even writing to the Console may help you narrow down you issue.

Comment: Although I have not discovered the root cause for this IDE/debugger crash, I did discover that my code was deadlocking because it was blocking on async code in a UI context. See: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html. This explains why my sample app hung. It may also explain why I saw this crash in unit test code, although the unit test engine does not run in a UI context, and again - I should not be able to crash the IDE (IMO). I followed Stephen Cleary's advice for avoiding the deadlock issues and I now have code that runs clean in both unit tests and samples.

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties window of your winrt project application. Change the Application Process from Managed Only to Mixed (Managed and Native) in debug tab